# Tools or techniques for merging multiple DLLs into a single file in .NET 6

Tags: c#, deployment, .net-6.0, fody-costura, ilrepack

I'm currently migrating a project from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 6. In the build pipeline the following tools are in use:

- **ILRepack or ILMerge**: for merging multiple XML files into one XML
- **Costura.Fody**: for merging multiple DLLs into a single DLL
- **SmartAssembly or .NET Reactor**: for obfuscation purposes and merging multiple DLLs into a single DLL

All these tools work great for .NET Framework assemblies but are incompatible with .NET 6.
[image: ILRepack]

[image: dotnet publish]
[image: SmartAssembly]

I'm aware of the single-file deployment technique in .NET 6 but the publishment of single files only work for executables and **not for libraries.** I tested this by trying to publish a .NET 6 library as a single file (see image above).

I can't find a lot of other techniques or tools for .NET 6 while searching the Internet.

What tools or techniques for merging multiple DLLs into a single file are there for .NET 6?

Comment: ILmerge is another option , but it has been deprecated as it is legacy and is no longer maintained.